# Cleaning Google App Engine project in Eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a dumb question.

Do you know if cleaning a google app engine project in eclipse also generates the cloud endpoint client library ? or i have to generate it seperately ? Its just that every change im doing to an endpoint's signature takes forever to build and im wondering if im just doing the same thing twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing a clean does in fact generate the cloud endpoint client library if you have "Build Automatically" selected.

We need to change the behavior so that the regeneration is not done automatically, but lets the user know that the client libraries are out-of-date and gives them the option to update them.

Comment: thanks a lot. It will be really nice if you will add this fix you're talking about. At least it will make me smoke less (while waiting for these builds to finish).